# How to find the least, greatest, minimal, amd maximal elements from this matrix?

Tags: matrices, relations, order-theory

[image]

I've shown that it's an order but I'm not sure how to find the least, greatest, minimal, and maximal elements. a,b,c,d aren't defined which confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ can be defined to correspond to rows $0,1,2,$ and $3$ of the matrix. Row $3$ says for instance that $c$ $R$ $a$, $c$ $R$ $b$, and $c$ $R$ $c$, but that $c$ does not $R$ $d$. Does this give you enough information to solve the problem?

Comment: I know about that part but I'm still unsure of how to find the elements.

Comment: How about writing out all the relations this matrix implies, in terms of a $\leq$ sign? $a \leq c$, $ a \leq d$, $b \leq c$, $b \leq d$... Does this make the soln clearer? It might be helpful to draw a lattice, if you know how.

Comment: How do you know to use the less than/equal to sign?

Comment: It is the standard relational symbol for an order.

Comment: Ok I came up with a possible solution. I said d is greatest, a and b are minimal, and there is no least or maximal element. How does that sound?

Comment: Close! You are correct that there is no least element, because $a$ and $b$ are both minimal. But remember that a greatest element is always the single maximal element.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks for the help!